# Error running tests with Karma only whilst using --single-run flag

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Karma and Jasmine to do unit testing on some Javascript files that I have. If I run the tests on a karma server which has been started, then there are no issues and the tests run and pass:

```
karma start karma.conf.js
02 09 2015 13:51:13.218:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, openhttp://localhost:9876/
02 09 2015 13:51:13.226:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
02 09 2015 13:51:13.230:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
02 09 2015 13:51:14.128:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket nE6zCoofERlwxbdEAAAA with id 11156374
02 09 2015 13:51:14.198:WARN [web-server]: 404: /img.png
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.003 secs / 0.023 secs)
```

I am however trying to make these tests run automatically on Jenkins, so this command isn't suitable as the server continues to run which stops the build from completing. Setting the `--single-run` flag to true *should* be the solution but it produces the following error:

```
karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
02 09 2015 15:01:57.755:DEBUG [config]: autoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
02 09 2015 15:01:57.759:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from /usr/local/lib/node_modules
02 09 2015 15:01:57.761:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine.
02 09 2015 15:01:57.762:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
02 09 2015 15:01:57.826:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
02 09 2015 15:01:57.830:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
02 09 2015 15:01:57.830:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/3d/j75hlwl97r37nsdgn72ypq28dp4wp2/T/karma-61237386
02 09 2015 15:01:57.835:DEBUG [launcher]: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/3d/j75hlwl97r37nsdgn72ypq28dp4wp2/T/karma-61237386/capture.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.655:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
02 09 2015 15:01:58.664:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.687:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket -EQr1esSnrr2-1vpAAAA
02 09 2015 15:01:58.690:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=-EQr1esSnrr2-1vpAAAA
02 09 2015 15:01:58.706:INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket -EQr1esSnrr2-1vpAAAA with id 61237386
02 09 2015 15:01:58.706:DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 61237386) captured in 0.879 secs
02 09 2015 15:01:58.714:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
02 09 2015 15:01:58.715:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?578a1e5ff14db21b04e2d6db7fd0eda37042440c /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.715:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.716:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.717:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?4a7da64f416169520c9d5c43b5a7feac6bde9104 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.717:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.717:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.718:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/wayfinder.js?016cf222a0fd28ad11af6a205a0840adba05bc9d /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.718:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/wayfinder.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.718:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /absolute/usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?3030709c83121e1b2ca4d1e657306b834fc13350 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.718:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.718:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js?0fed45ad7a48ace869bc725ca474ad86a1ef1562 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.js?6b6a0b033c91fd914999d9ce32fc49b567032e3d /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.draw.js?607b1f1da44ef7ca11efa37da98a77b27db11d6f /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.draw.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.719:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/wayfinder.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.720:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /usr/local/lib/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.720:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.720:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.721:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.draw.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.721:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/tests/floorcontroller.test.js?f91ff99985cffbfc55d744029683c60283bc709d /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.721:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/tests/floorcontroller.test.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.721:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/python-models.js?86bc9bb6d49f1a9a2ca5b38037eedf6436774053 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.721:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/python-models.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.distortableimage.js?8c54672d7373c4c51abd6d544949e8953f86d482 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.distortableimage.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /base/Website/static/js/shared/floorcontroller.js?e00e8e03e847f9415ef608dc97183f9f90570bd4 /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/shared/floorcontroller.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/tests/floorcontroller.test.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/python-models.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.722:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.distortableimage.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.723:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/shared/floorcontroller.js
02 09 2015 15:01:58.775:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Requesting /img.png /
02 09 2015 15:01:58.775:DEBUG [middlware:source-files]: Fetching /img.png
02 09 2015 15:01:58.776:WARN [web-server]: 404: /img.png
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.003 secs / 0.023 secs)
02 09 2015 15:01:58.786:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b[0][0]')
  at /Users/tll01/Documents/way-finder/Website/static/js/python-models.js:4
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0.023 secs)
02 09 2015 15:01:58.788:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
02 09 2015 15:01:58.788:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
02 09 2015 15:01:58.796:DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exited with code 0
02 09 2015 15:01:58.797:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir /var/folders/3d/j75hlwl97r37nsdgn72ypq28dp4wp2/T/karma-61237386
```

Just to clarify, `b[0][0]` is an object in the javascript files. What I'm confused about is what the `--single-run` flag actually does. My assumption was that it just shuts the server down after the tests run. Why does it affect the actual running of the tests? Here is the karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Aug 26 2015 11:39:13 GMT+0100 (BST)

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.js',
  'Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.draw.js',
  'Website/static/js/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js',
  'Website/static/js/wayfinder.js',
  'Website/static/js/shared/floorcontroller.js',
  'Website/static/js/tests/*.js',
  'Website/static/js/python-models.js',
  'Website/static/js/leaflet/leaflet.distortableimage.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {

},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
})
}
```

My unit tests:

```
describe("Floor controller", function() {
    var div;

    beforeEach(function(){
        div = $("<div id='map'></div>");
        $(document.body).append(div);
        floorplan0 = new floorplan(['img.png', 0, 3]);
        floorplan1 = new floorplan(['img.png', 0, 1]);
        floorplan2 = new floorplan(['img.png', 0, 2]);
        floorController = new floorControls([0,1,2,3], { position: 'bottomright'});
        floorplans = [floorplan0, floorplan1, floorplan2];
        building1 = new building([[[2,2], [1,1]], 'building'])
        buildings = [building1];
        floorController.onAdd();
        loadMap();
    });

    it("should be initialised", function() {
        expect(floorController._level).toEqual(0);

    });

    it("should return the correct button labels", function() {
        var levels = [-1, 0, 1];
        levels = floorController.assignFloorLabels(levels);
        expect(levels).toEqual(
            [
                {num: -1, label: 'B'},
                {num: 0, label: 'G'},
                {num: 1, label: 1}
            ]

            );
    });

    it("should set the correct level", function() {
        floorController.setLevel(1);
        expect(floorController.getLevel()).toEqual(1);
    });

//    it("should remove layers when switching levels", function() {
//        floorController.setLevel(1);
//        expect(imageOverlays).toEqual([]);
//        floorController.setLevel(3);
//         expect(imageOverlays).toEqual([]);
//    });

    afterEach(function(){
        div.remove();
        div = null;
    });
});
```

and also the python-models.js (although I doubt this is where the error is as this code is used repeatedly in our project without a problem):

```
function building(b) {
    this.name = b[1];
    this.bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        new L.LatLng(b[0][0][0], b[0][0][1]),
        new L.LatLng(b[0][1][0], b[0][1][1])
    );
}

function floorplan(f) {
    this.imageUrl = f[0];
    this.buildingIndex = f[1];
    this.floor = f[2];

    this.isOn = function(level) {
        return this.floor === level;
    }
}

function node(n) {
    this.name = n[0];
    this.coords = new L.LatLng(n[1][0], n[1][1]);
    this.floorNumber = n[2];
    this.type = n[3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load your test files last by adding them last in the files array.

When running with --single-run flag add also --no-auto-watch.

Another problem is that your tests run twice. If this persists after adding the --no-auto-watch check this post https://medium.com/@SchizoDuckie/so-your-karma-tests-run-twice-this-is-what-you-need-to-do-be74ce9f257e. It basically says to add { pattern:'tests/*.js', included: false } instead of 'tests/*.js'

Comment: I've updated the log to LOG_DEBUG and included the javascript file. The debug log has some interesting parts at the end. It seems it completes the tests with 3/3 SUCCESS but then gets the error after exiting... I honestly have no idea why it would be doing this.

Comment: Very confusing indeed. Try moving this line 'Website/static/js/tests/*.js' to be the last item in the files array. Also you can use the basePath property to have 'Website/static/js' only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "singleRun" to true in the Karma config file itself, instead of setting the flag in the command.

```
 // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same error whether I set it in the config file or by the command line. I'd prefer to set it by command line so that I can use the auto watch feature whilst developing.